# Can colonists benefit of service in another dome (there are not living in)?

Tags: surviving-mars

By example, there is no space to build a school in a dome A, but dome B is near and have one.

Can colonists benefit of service in another dome (there are not living in)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of the Opportunity update, yes!

You can build passages between domes. A colonist can work or use service buildings in any dome that is connected directly to their home dome. However, colonists receive a small penalty to comfort received or their job performance if they have to travel to another dome.

Comment: I really hope a patch change it in the future, at least for nearby domes.

Comment: Some sort of transit system would be fun, everything is better with monorails.

Comment: @ig_42 I heard those things are awfully loud.